# Google Play service v7 and google Map v2

Tags: android, google-maps

Everybody was passed a worst day with google map v2 in Emulator , so I ask question if Google play service v7 resolve a problem with emulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.I dont think so. Still a same issue will be faced in emulator. you want to test only in real device for Google maps with signed apk for release key and for unsigned apk debug key to test in real device.

Comment: Thank you , I think I will wait until they resolved this error !!